# Why does this code not wait for input

Tags: java, loops, input

I expect the code to stop and wait for input again, but instead it runs as if the user just hit enter every time, creating a infinite loop.

```
while(asking) {
    try {   
        int answer = input.nextInt();   
    }
    catch(Exception InputMismatchException) { 
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
    }
}
```

Why does it do this?

EDIT: I am not worried about *exiting* the while loop. The problem is that it will not wait for input.

EDIT2: It runs as expected if the exception isn't triggered. (I.E the user entered a number within the integer limit)

Comment: you need to call `nextLine` in case you are getting an execption. Otherwise it´s creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Which value has asking and when does it change?

Comment: Where are you setting `asking`?

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda It doesn't matter, set it to true and never change it the problem will be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing value of `asking` inside `while` loop, so it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. nextInt is not blocking. nextLine does.

```
while(asking) {
    int answer;
    try {   
        answer = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    }
    catch(Exception NumberFormatException) { 
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
while(asking) {
    try {   
        int answer = input.nextInt();   
    }
    catch(Exception InputMismatchException) { 
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
        input.next();
    }
}
```